# How can I find which app slows down my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, performance

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3.

My phone is becoming slow. I don't know how to find the app that slows it down. Can someone help me with this? My guess that the app is FACEBOOK... worst app ever.

After restart, the phone works fine for some time. Then, it slows down again and becomes lagged.

Comment: You could check the active apps when it gets laggy, then reboot and wait until it gets laggy again to check one more time the active apps. If you repeat this a couple of times you should end with a couple of apps that will be there all the time that you've checked, so you can narrow the search.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to use some live monitoring app, e.g. [OS Monitor](http://www.appbrain.com/app/os-monitor/com.eolwral.osmonitor). These usually offer you a view on apps currently consuming most of the ressources, e.g. hogging your CPU, eating your RAM, or utilizing your network:

[image: OS Monitor: CPU] [image: OS Monitor: Connections]
<sup>OS Monitor showing running processes, and showing network connections (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Running processes can be sorted by several criteria, such as name, CPU usage, and more. The device being "laggy" most times means some app consumes all CPU power, or I/O, or RAM – so this should help you figuring out.

An alternative to mention is [SystemPanel](http://www.appbrain.com/app/systempanellite-task-manager/nextapp.systempanel), which even offers you a manual (for your situation, the [system monitor page](http://android.nextapp.com/site/systempanel/doc/systemmonitor) would apply). In its payed version, it even offers you background monitoring, so you could first let it collect data for a while, and later check for the "largest consumers".

[image: SystemPanel processes] [image: SystemPanel ressources]
<sup>SystemPanel: running processes, overall ressources (click images for larger variants)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you already suspect a particular app (Facebook in this case), just uninstall it and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, the Facebook app is known to cause performance issues on Android and iOS. [1](http://bgr.com/2016/02/01/facebook-android-app-battery-life-performance/), [2](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/facebook-android-battery-life-down-reduced-a6846941.html),  [3](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/improve-iphone-battery-life-delete-the-facebook-app/), [4](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3428088/Best-way-boost-phone-s-battery-life-Uninstall-Facebook-Tests-reveal-app-drains-power-slows-handsets-down.html)

Comment: @calebthebrewer It doesn't even matter whether it really is Facebook: I only mention it because the OP already named that app as his top suspect. Maybe somebody thought my answer was too obvious, but it really is the quickest and easiest way to test your suspicion.